# Set parameter to notification

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I'm using C# and Windows Phone 8.1 as Universal app. I can send notifications from background by this code:

```
    void ShowNotification(string title, string text)
    {
        ToastTemplateType toastTemplate = ToastTemplateType.ToastText02;

        XmlDocument toastXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(toastTemplate);
        XmlNodeList textElements = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");
        textElements[0].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode(title));
        textElements[1].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode(text));

        ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(new ToastNotification(toastXml));
    }
```

I wanna when user tapped on these notifications in action center, that message I wrote in notification shows on a textBlock in my MainPage but I don't know how can I set a parameter to do this. I used this code in MainPage but parameter is empty:

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e != null && e.Parameter != null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("MainPage.OnNavigatedTo.Parameter: " + e.Parameter.ToString());
        }
    }
```

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify app launch parameters like:

```
IXmlNode toastNode = toastXml.SelectSingleNode("/toast");
((XmlElement)toastNode).SetAttribute("launch", "{\"type\":\"toast\",\"param1\":\"12345\",\"param2\":\"67890\"}");
```

Then in app's onlaunched event, navigate to mainpage with the parameter you get as below:

```
rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), args.Arguments);
```